# com.android.phone crashes after PPP connects

Tags: android, android-source

This is relevant to a custom Android build so deals with the AOSP. It came as source but without any RIL or phone support. I have added the binary files from SIMCOM to the build and modified the build so that PHONE is included after a week or 2 messing around with Android 5.1.1 policies, I finally get it to dial up and connect via PPP. I can send and receive SMS messages and the issue is with the PPP connection after the connection.

I see this in the logcat output.

```
I/chat    ( 2926): send (ATD*99***1#^M)
I/chat    ( 2926): expect (CONNECT)
I/chat    ( 2926): ^M
I/chat    ( 2926): ^M
I/chat    ( 2926): CONNECT
I/chat    ( 2926):  -- got it
I/pppd    ( 2924): Serial connection established.
D/pppd    ( 2924): using channel 9
I/pppd    ( 2924): Using interface ppp0
I/pppd    ( 2924): Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB3
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1280> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x59f9be6b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x10 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x332fad98> <pcomp> <accomp>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x10 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x332fad98> <pcomp> <accomp>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <mru 1280> <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x59f9be6b> <pcomp> <accomp>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x11 magic=0x332fad98]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <c81669cbcc0c57607c5609f38a630dea>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <7b4baf8d89cc6dc0bac854ee8c6e86a0>, name = "wap"]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 ""]
I/pppd    ( 2924): CHAP authentication succeeded
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns3 0.0.0.0>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x12 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x8]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x8 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x5 <ms-dns3 10.11.12.14>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x6 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x9]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x9]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x6 <addr 10.11.240.107> <ms-dns1 192.168.39.28>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x7 <addr 10.11.240.107> <ms-dns1 192.168.39.28>]
D/pppd    ( 2924): rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x7 <addr 10.11.240.107> <ms-dns1 192.168.39.28>]
W/pppd    ( 2924): Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
I/pppd    ( 2924): local  IP address 10.11.240.107
I/pppd    ( 2924): remote IP address 10.64.64.64
I/pppd    ( 2924): primary   DNS address 192.168.39.28
I/pppd    ( 2924): secondary DNS address 10.11.12.14
```

After this I get an error followed by the exception below and then a window pops up saying com.android.phone has stopped.

```
D/TelephonyProvider( 2868): subIdString = 1 subId = 1
W/AppOps  (  416): Bad call: specified package android under uid 1001 but it is really 1000
D/TelephonyProvider( 2868): subIdString = 1 subId = 1
D/ConnectivityService(  416): setProvNotificationVisible: E visible=false networkType=0 action=com.android.internal.telephony.PROVISION0
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868): FATAL EXCEPTION: DcHandlerThread
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868): Process: com.android.phone, PID: 2868
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868): java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 1001
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerNetworkAgent(IConnectivityManager.java:2030)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkAgent(ConnectivityManager.java:2001)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.net.NetworkAgent.<init>(NetworkAgent.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DataConnection$DcNetworkAgent.<init>(DataConnection.java:1958)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at com.android.internal.telephony.dataconnection.DataConnection$DcActiveState.enter(DataConnection.java:1735)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.invokeEnterMethods(StateMachine.java:1008)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.performTransitions(StateMachine.java:854)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler.handleMessage(StateMachine.java:800)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2868):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
D/ConnectivityService(  416): setProvNotificationVisibleIntent: E visible=false networkType=0 extraInfo=null
W/ActivityManager(  416): Process com.android.phone has crashed too many times: killing!
```

It would appear to be a file or device read issue due to the exception but I can't trace down what that file or device might be or which process is trying to access it, possibly ttyUSB3 which is the port for PPP.

Currently /dev/ttyUSB3 has system:radio ownership to get the PPP to connect.

After many days on this I've been unable to get this resolved to look for some fresh input to this issue. (The source for this will be published once this works and it is for the FriendlyArm NanoPC T3)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have finally tracked this down and fixed it so that it can work but the issue that causes this is still in the code.

The fault is caused when NetworkMonitor handles the CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SERVER using the property ro.net.captive_server in setprop.

```
mServer = Settings.Global.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Global.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SERVER);
if (mServer == null) {
    mServer = SystemProperties.get("ro.net.captive_server");
    if (mServer == null || mServer.length() == 0) {
        mServer = DEFAULT_SERVER;
    } else {
        Settings.Global.putString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SERVER, mServer);
    }
}
```

By commenting out the ro.net.captive_portal in the setprop file, the connection now uses the default server for connection checking.

The fault lies in the line where Settings.Global.putString is called. This causes an exception. Why? I do not yet know.

By removing the property, the PPP connection now works 100%